# FullCalendar Yii Module: actionList function in MainController.php

Tags: yii, fullcalendar, yii-extensions

I'm trying to gain an understanding of how/where the $start and $end variables are being passed to the actionList function in the MainController.php script of the FullCalendar Yii Module:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cal/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

```
public function actionList($start = 0, $end = 0)
{
    if ((Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) and (Yii::app()->user->hasState('calUserId')) )
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
                    'condition' => 'user_id=:user_id',
                    'params'=>array(':user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('calUserId')),
                ));
        $criteria->addBetweenCondition('start', $start, $end);
        $events = Event::model()->findAll($criteria);
        echo CJSON::encode($events);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

Does this come from the fullcalendar.min.js script?  The only place it seems to be called is in eventCal.js:

```
var defaultCalendarOptions = {
        events: params.baseUrl+'list',
```

Are variables ever passed in using the Yii module or are they always $start=0,$end=0?  If they are passed in, please explain how...

Comment: a link to this module will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$start` and `$end` variables are actually `$_GET` parameters that are passed to the `actionList` method. The Yii framework often does this - if an action method has parameters, it looks for `$_GET` parameters of the same name and passes those instead.

You made a good assumption that the `events: params.baseUrl+'list'` line is used for this, but the actual piece of code that sends the GET request is buried deep inside the fullcalendar.js file:

```
$.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, {
    data: data,
    ...
```

In this code, `source` is the `events` parameter from above, which gets passed to the actual fullcalendar script and `data` is an array with the `start` and `end` parameters. You can find the full source of the script [here](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js). The extension you're using only has the minified version.

Comment: That makes better sense, thanks for the thorough explanation.